# React Native scroll view not showing

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, flexbox, react-native

I have a scroll view at the top level of the view hierarchy. I'm trying to get it to show its content but I haven't had any luck.

I see that the documentation says scroll views need a bounded height to work. I can't seem to get it to have a bounded height. This is what I have so far.

```
'use strict';

const React = require('react-native');
const {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  BackAndroid,
  TextInput,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  ScrollView
} = React;

const ActionButton = require('./action-button'),
    Dimensions = require('Dimensions');

module.exports = React.createClass({
  handleBackButtonPress () {
    if (this.props.navigator) {
      this.props.navigator.pop();
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  },

  componentWillMount () {
    BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonPress);
  },

  componentWillUnmount () {
    BackAndroid.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonPress);
  },

  onInputFocus (refName) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let scrollResponder = this.refs.getScrollResponder();
      scrollResponder.scrollNativeHandleToKeyboard(
        React.findNodeHandle(this.refs[refName]),
        110,
        true
      );
    }, 50);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.scrollWrapper}>
        <ScrollView ref='scrollView' style={styles.scroller}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
              <Text>New Post</Text>

                <View style={styles.actions}>
                  <ActionButton handler={this.handleBackButtonPress} icon={'fontawesome|close'}
                    size={15} width={15} height={15} />
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.content}>
              <TextInput underlineColorAndroid={'white'}
                placeholder={'Who\'s your professor?'}
                ref='professor'
                onFocus={this.onInputFocus.bind(this, 'professor')}
                />

              <TextInput multiline={true}
                underlineColorAndroid={'white'}
                placeholder={'What do you think?'}
                ref='post'
                onFocus={this.onInputFocus.bind(this, 'post')}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.footer}>
              <TouchableNativeFeedback
                background={TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackground()}>

                <View style={{width: 50, height: 25, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
                  <Text>Submit</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableNativeFeedback>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollWrapper: {
    flex: 1
  },
  scroller: {
    flex: 1
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 5,
  },
  post: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  actions: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  header: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    height: 35,
    padding: 5,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 35
  },
  footer: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    height: 35
  }
});
```

**EDIT:** So I changed the background colors of all the components to something obvious. I was able to simplify the view, so now the ScrollView is the root of the component. The container view (the immediate child of the ScrollView) is the one who isn't filling all the available space. I'm still playing around with it but any help is much appreciated.

Comment: it's useful to make the background color of a component an obvious color (like red) to see what its dimensions are.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, you need to set `flex: 1` to the parent's view. Then, for ScrollView, use `contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}` rather than using style.

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}>
     ...
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using position: absolute, you need to specify a left:0, right:0 for it to work with your current setup, though I am not entirely sure position: absolute is needed at all. Try this:

```
content: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 35,
    left:0,
    right:0,
    bottom:0
},
```

Comment: I'm using absolute positioning because it gives me more control over where the elements are on the view. Unfortunately your suggestion didn't work. I'm still playing around with it though.

Comment: Any solution to this? facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `removeClippedSubviews={false}` as a property of  and see what happens.